# Excel - How to split a string by a list of delimiters

Tags: microsoft-excel, string-manipulation

As part of a board game logging tool, I want to be able to split a string.

The string may consist of the following:

Allowed characters: 00,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,C,B,R. Besides 00, any numbers will always be single digit

if 0 or 00 appears, it will be the entire string, so I guess it can be disregarded in the general case, and be handled seperately with a simpler IF clause

My desired result is:

[image: Image: Splitting string in A1 into a number of cells]

Is there any way I can use the SUBSTITUTE function, and somehow supply a list of  delimiting characters, instead of nested SUBSTITUTE calls?

.Morten

Comment: Why BBB2 and not just B... why not C6? The rules are not clear to me.

Comment: Does your source string contain the `,`, or did you add those for readability in the question?

Comment: Your needs seem difficult to achieve. Your source data doesn't have a special format, and your split doesn't seem to have a particular logic.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (simple (sigh...)) occurred to me while answering. I shall leave the rest as further examples that work, and might help someone if they can't apply this simpler idea:

```
=MID(A1, SEQUENCE(1,7), IF(SEQUENCE(1,7)<7, 1, LEN (A1)-6) )
```

It uses the basic "MID - SOURCE - NUMBER OF CHARACTERS TO WORK ON" approach, limiting the last to 7 since you want to extract 7 pieces of data. (Otherwise you get "BB2", "B2" and "2" in columns I-K, or errors, depending.) The trick is to, duh, leave the `IF()-ing` IN the last clause, rather than base the whole approach on starting with an `IF()` and fitting everything into it!

Naturally, it can be modified for any more oddness with that last cell (H1).

The "old" answer:

If you don't mind an old-style CSE formula, then the following will reproduce the results you show in your question:

```
{=IF( COLUMN()-1<7, MID(A1,COLUMN()-1,1), RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-6))}
```

(The curly braces achieved by pressing `Control-Shift-Enter`, of course.)

The current spill approaches won't work in a bare `IF()` like I used. I did not find a function to wrap it in that would force the `Spill` functionality without altering the results.

Using `Spill` techniques directly, I failed to achieve the "odd man out" last cell.

If the last cell is not just a repository for any characters exceeding six, it would need adjusting accordingly. This part was not explained in any way in your question so... Adjustments can be made to the values `COLUMN()` produces to fit into the precise columns you really end up using, or left as is if just as shown.

Alternatively, and BETTER, one could use the `Spill` functionality to get cells in the first six columns (B through G) filled, then have a different formula for column H:

```
=MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,6),1)
```

for columns B-G, and

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-6)
```

for column H.

(It would avoid the CSE aspect, which locks the cells with each row's formula together almost as much as merged cells do. Perhaps easier to maintain in the future because the formulas are direct to the point, not combined into a larger formula that does two different things.)

By the way, `MID()` with `SEQUENCE()` is a great new technique `Spill` brings to us. Doesn't have to be single characters like here, can be any number of them.